# group by/having strange behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

i am facing a very weird problem.

Basically i need to extract a set of rows from a table where every row is the "oldest" in its own group.

The table is structured as follow:

- id, integer
- domain_id, integer
- value, integer
- created_at, datetime

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM domains_urls GROUP BY domain_id HAVING created_at = MAX(created_at)
```

If i am not wrong, it should group the rows by domain_id and extract the one that it matches created_at = MAX(created_at).

The point is that it does not work as expected!

The table content is

```
id   domain_id    value    created_at
1    2            1        2014-05-25 10:30:13
2    1            3        2014-05-25 19:30:13
3    2            2        2014-05-25 11:30:13
4    2            7        2014-05-25 15:30:13
5    2            4        2014-05-25 12:30:13
6    2            5        2014-05-25 13:30:13
```

I should get two rows:

```
id   domain_id    value    created_at
2    1            3        2014-05-25 19:30:13
4    2            7        2014-05-25 15:30:13
```

Instead i get only

```
id   domain_id    value    created_at
4    2            7        2014-05-25 15:30:13
```

I'm using MySQL 5.5 on Windows 7

I need to use an HAVING+GROUP BY or a DISTINCT+ORDER BY (not tested).

Thanks!

EDIT:

Because i am a dumb (i should avoid working on sunday), the value returned by MAX is related to the table and not to the group!

Comment: Why do you need to use HAVING+GROUP BY or DISTINCT+ORDER BY?

Comment: Because i'm using an ORM and because i need performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Select * from urls as u group by u.id having u.created >= any (select created from urls u2 where u.id == u2.id)
```

i have not tested this, just wrote that from the top of my head

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by joining the table back to itself using the `max(created_at)`:

```
select du.*
from domains_urls du
  join (select domain_id, max(created_at) maxcreated_at
        from domains_urls
        group by domain_id
        ) du2 on du.domain_id = du2.domain_id 
                 and du.created_at = du2.maxcreated_at
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6dae4/2)